# Openssl no IV in SMIME module

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm trying to understand a particular difference between 2 encryption modules in openssl. One module is "openssl enc" and the other is "openssl smime". I understand that SMIME is often used for email and that openssl enc is used for generic encryption/decryption routines. My confusion is the fact that the openssl enc module allows you to specify a key, an initialization vector, and a salt, but the openssl smime module only lets you specify a key. What is the reason for this? Does the smime module assume a particular IV and salt under the hood? I am specifically using the CBC mode of AES in this case.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww The site you listed says you can post regarding:
1. Software algorithms
2. Software tools commonly used by programmers.

I see this post as asking about both of these. Therefore, the post seems relevant to stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two commands are very different.

Openssl enc encrypts according to your specs. So if you want aes-256-cbc, for example, you can say:

```
$ more foo.txt
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
$ openssl rand -hex 16
12b53ed0a13749832fe92d1e00f8b4db
$ openssl rand -hex 32
8cc103b653a10f0ea884482e4cdd0615160930e840d00af12e33ac560a830bd0
$ openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -in foo.txt -out foo.enc -K 8cc103b653a10f0ea884482e4cdd0615160930e840d00af12e33ac560a830bd0 -iv 12b53ed0a13749832fe92d1e00f8b4db
$ base64 foo.enc
7wiOhwD9WEm4h2Y9ooDFlEFPkIX6gU+6Xm6ca9P1t+z7S83Vk95WwOezSd2Hv2A1
$ openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in foo.enc -K 8cc103b653a10f0ea884482e4cdd0615160930e840d00af12e33ac560a830bd0 -iv 12b53ed0a13749832fe92d1e00f8b4db
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

In this example, foo.txt is 44 bytes long, the encrypted message is 48 bytes (3 * block length, including padding), so that's the raw AES encrypted data.

Openssl smime constructs a [S/MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) message according to [RFC 3447](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt). This means, it uses [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), where the actual message is encrypted symmetrically, with a random key and IV. the IV is embedded in the message, the key is then encrypted using the [public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) from the certificate you specify on the command line. If the message is to be signed, too, then the private key is taken either from the certificate in the -signer argument or directly from the file specified by -inkey.

The message is then encoded in [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One). A typical openssl smime output might then look like this in a [decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/):

```
SEQUENCE(2 elem)
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER  1.2.840.113549.1.7.3
  [0](1 elem)
    SEQUENCE(3 elem)
      INTEGER  0
      SET(1 elem)
      # Certificate information, issuer and serial number
      OCTET STRING(128 byte) 73CE9886...                         # RSA encrypted key
      SEQUENCE(3 elem)
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.1.7.1
        SEQUENCE(2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2                # AES-128-CBC
          OCTET STRING(16 byte) D2A3ECBAE792CFC19DD696AEF9593BB3 # random IV
        [0](48 byte) A14F3F76...                                 # encrypted message
```

Comment: That's great information. What do you mean by "the IV is embedded in the message"? Does that mean that openssl generates a random IV for you under the hood? What about a salt?

Comment: Oh, you did indicate that the key and IV were randomly generated. However, the salt is still a missing piece.

Comment: Salt is needed to assure that two messages encrypted with the same password are still different. If you provide the key and iv in detail, the iv is a salt of sorts. But strictly speaking, salt is used only if you derive the key from a user input aka password. In this case, openssl enc embeds the salt in the message, just like openssl smime embeds the iv.